# WP pagination in rest api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

we have made a custom api to get all the post in descending order and we want to add  pagination in that api, I have read other questions and answers also but didnt get any idea so can some one explain me with a simple code with pagination so that I can understand how it works.

This is my code so how can I add pagination can anyone explain to me because I searched other questaion also but I didnt get any idea.

```
define('API_ENDPOINT_VERSION',1);

//flush the rewrite rules on plugin activation

function apiendpoint_activate()
{
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'apiendpoint_activate');

function apiendpoint_register_endpoints(){
    register_rest_route(
        'api/v1',
        '/post',
        [
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' =>'api_get_post',
        ]
    );

}
add_action('rest_api_init','apiendpoint_register_endpoints');

function api_get_post($request){
    $ar = array( 'post_type'=>'post',
         'posts_per_page'=>15,
         'orderby' => 'date',
         'order' => 'DESC',
       );
    $posts = get_posts($ar);
    //var_dump($posts);
    //exit;
    $a = array();

    if($posts){
        foreach ($posts as $post) {


        $a[]= array(   
        'title'=>$post->post_title,
         'link'=>get_the_permalink($post->ID),
         'category'=>get_the_category($post->ID),
         'published_date'=>get_the_date('l, F j, Y',$post->ID),
          'guid'=>$post->guid,
          'image'=>get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID,'large'),
           'description'=>$post->post_excerpt,
           'source'=>"Nepaljapan"
        //'img'=>$img
        );
        }
        return $a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ajay Do you want paging for custom post type or default post type "posts"?

Comment: And is there a reason to use the Custom Rest Endpoint? Have you tried using default endpoints?

Comment: hi @jeni pagination for post type "post" in wp custom ret api

Comment: Check my latest snippet to as an answer. Hope this helps! Accept the answer if it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
define('API_ENDPOINT_VERSION', 1);

//flush the rewrite rules on plugin activation

function apiendpoint_activate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules(); } register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'apiendpoint_activate');

function apiendpoint_register_endpoints() {
    register_rest_route(
        'api/v1',
        '/post',
        [
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'api_get_post',
        ]
    );

} add_action('rest_api_init', 'apiendpoint_register_endpoints');

function api_get_post($request) {
    $ar = array('post_type' => 'posts',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => ($_REQUEST['paged'] ? $_REQUEST['paged'] : 1) 
); 

$posts = get_posts($ar); //var_dump($posts); //exit; $a = array();

if ($posts) {
    foreach($posts as $post) {


        $a[] = array(
            'title' => $post -> post_title,
            'link' => get_the_permalink($post -> ID),
            'category' => get_the_category($post -> ID),
            'published_date' => get_the_date('l, F j, Y', $post -> ID),
            'guid' => $post -> guid,
            'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post -> ID, 'large'),
            'description' => $post -> post_excerpt,
            'source' => "Nepaljapan"
            //'img'=>$img
        );
    }
    return $a; } 
}
```

Call API call as below:

> /wp-json/api/v1/post?paged=1

Increase the **paged** value by 1 to get next paging posts.

Hope this helps!